# How to add a button to access photo gallery to keyboard in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, gallery

I'm building a chat app and I'd like to add the opportunity to send image. That's why I'd like to add a shortcut on the keyboard to access gallery or phone's camera.

I don't see it in the native keyboard type (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype) so I guess I've to do it programatically.

I've found nothing about it on the stackOverflow nor on the internet.

I'd like to have access to a keyboard like the one you can have in iMessage for example.

Comment: You might be looking for [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own view above the keyboard by editing NSLayoutConstraint constants. Here is an example storyboard.

[storyboard and constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRt36.png)

Then:

- Connect your NSLayoutConstraint to the View Controller

`@IBOutlet weak var overKeyboardViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`

- Add keyboard listeners in your viewDidLoad method:

  ```
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
  ```
- Create selectors for keyboard

  `@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [unowned self, keyboardSize] in
                      self.overKeyboardViewBottomConstraint.constant =  keyboardSize.height
                      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                  }
              }
          }
  @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [unowned self] in
          self.overKeyboardViewBottomConstraint.constant =  0
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      }
  }`
- Then your camera IBAction

  `@IBAction func cameraAction(_ sender: Any) {
      let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
      switch photos {
      case .notDetermined:
          print("not determined")
          PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
              if status == .authorized{
                  self.showGallery()
              } else {
                  print("access denied")
              }
          })
      case .authorized:
          print("authorized")
          self.showGallery()
      case .denied:
          print("denied")
      default:
          break
      }
  }`
- Finally your Gallery Function

  `func showGallery() {
          if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
              let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
              imagePicker.delegate = self
              imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary;
              imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
              self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
          }
      }`